# elasticsearch update mapping conflict exception

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index named "myproject-error-2016-08" which has only one type named "error".

When I hit :

```
GET myproject-error-2016-08/_mapping
```

It returns following result:

```
{
   "myproject-error-2016-08": {
      "mappings": {
         "error": {
            "properties": {
               ...
               "responseCode": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               ...
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I need to update the responseCode to not_analyzed,
hence I am using following following reuest :

```
PUT myproject-error-2016-08/_mapping/error
{
   "properties": {
      "responseCode": {
         "type": "string",
         "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
   }
}
```

And getting following exception :

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Mapper for [responseCode] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [responseCode] has different [index] values, mapper [responseCode] has different [doc_values] values, cannot change from disabled to enabled, mapper [responseCode] has different [analyzer]]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "Mapper for [responseCode] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [responseCode] has different [index] values, mapper [responseCode] has different [doc_values] values, cannot change from disabled to enabled, mapper [responseCode] has different [analyzer]]"
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

I have also tried following:

```
PUT myproject-error-2016-08/_mapping/error?update_all_types
{
...
}
```

But it returned the same response.

Elastic Search is :

```
$ ./elasticsearch -version
Version: 2.3.5, Build: 90f439f/2016-07-27T10:36:52Z, JVM: 1.8.0_91
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You [cannot change the type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings) of a field once it's been created.

However, you can definitely create a `not_analyzed` sub-field like this:

```
PUT myproject-error-2016-08/_mapping/error
{
   "properties": {
      "responseCode": {
         "type": "string",
         "fields": {
            "raw": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then you'll need to [re-index your data/logs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) in order to populate that sub-field and you'll be able to reference `responseCode.raw` in your queries.

**UPDATE:** Since ES5 `not_analyzed` `string` do not exist anymore and are now called `keyword`:

```
PUT myproject-error-2016-08/_mapping/error
{
   "properties": {
      "responseCode": {
         "type": "text",
         "fields": {
            "raw": {
               "type": "keyword"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Val, It worked :) , however I can not see the responseCode.raw in Kibana, Do I need to configure it in any other way to access it from Kibana ?

Comment: You need to re-create the index pattern in Kibana so that the new field can be discovered.

Comment: "Refresh field list" action worked and I got the new field in field list, thanks man :)

Comment: Or that... yes ! Glad you figured it out!

Comment: `/_reindex` and `/_aliases` was the perfect solution for me.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70922185/4845324