# ElasticSearch Define Custom Mapping Conflict With Default `_doc` Mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

this problem happen when try to create custom mapping type.
after create custom mapping for first insert elastic want to create `_doc` mapping type and conflict happen here.

in first step i create a mapping

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "field1": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "field2": {
                "type": "short",
                "index": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and into the second step put first data in elastic

```
curl --location --request PUT 'localhost:9200/myindex/mydoc/1

{
    "field1": "first info",
    "field2": 0
}
```

but in second step when i try to put first data into the elastic encounter following error

```
 "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "Mapper for [field2] conflicts with existing mapper:\n\tCannot update parameter [index] from [false] to [true]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Mapper for [field2] conflicts with existing mapper:\n\tCannot update parameter [index] from [false] to [true]"
    },
    "status": 400
```

seems to in this step elastic try to create dynamic mapping and this mapping want to create field2 as index field.

also according to another answers i used from `dynamic: false` or `dynamic: "strict"` setting in mapping like follow block code but it is not work

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "dynamic": false,
        "properties": {
            "field1": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "field2": {
                "type": "short",
                "index": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this error also happen for type of fields. for example my field type is "keyword" but on auto mapping try to convert this type to "text"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of create custom explicit mapping can define a mapping template like following code

```
curl --location --request PUT 'localhost:9200/_template/my-custom-type?include_type_name=true' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "index_patterns": [
        "my-index"
    ],
    "mappings": {
        "my-custom-type": {
            "properties": {
                "field1": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "field2": {
                    "type": "short",
                    "index": false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

after do this not exist any mapping yet but with first insert, mapping will be created according to above structure!

```
curl --location --request PUT 'localhost:9200/my-index/my-custom-type/1' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "field1": "SaeedMozaffari",
    "field2": 0
}'
```

with this trick elastic don't create `_doc` mapping so don't update any type in your mapping so this error will not be happen!

Answer (score 0):

[`dynamic` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic.html#dynamic-parameters) of Elasticsearch, have default value as `true`. When trying to replicate your issue, I followed the below steps

1. Create a new index with the given index mapping

```
PUT <index-name>
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "field1": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "field2": {
        "type": "short",
        "index": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. Index data into the new index. *According to the question, I should not be able to index the data, and elasticsearch will return mapper parsing exception.*

```
POST <index-name>/_doc/1
{
  "field1": "first info",
  "field2": 0
}
```

**But following the above steps, I am able to successfully, index the data in the index.**

---

> The index option controls whether field values are indexed. It accepts
> true or false and defaults to true. Fields that are not indexed are
> not queryable.

**The error which you are getting will occur only when you are trying to update the `index` param of the `field2`.**

Initially, when you have created the index mapping with `field2` having `index` param set to false, this cannot be updated to `true`. (this is referred to as conflicting changes)

If you want to update the `index` param, then you have to create a new index with new index mapping, and index the documents in it, which can be done using reindex API.

Comment: @Saeed please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: thanks. I find answer and will be posted soon.